# Sharepoint 2010: Copy or add file to Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document-library

I have a silverlight application inserted in a SharePoint page. The SilverLight application runs on a different server thatn that of SharePoint. From an event in the SilverLight, I generate a document on the server side from SQL Server. I can generate the doc on the server hosting the silverlight application and also copy it to the SharePoint server. I wanted to know if I can include this file in a sharepoint document library automatically. I was thinking if like emailing to a list allows us to copy the file into the library, can we **configure the reverse, means copying the file make it part of the list**.

**Update:**

I wanted to avoid uploading. For me uploading is sending the file from one location to the target location. But what I am saying is, if I copy the file into the folder where SharePoint keeps the file physically for the particular list, can it be added to the list automatically?

I am not sure, how well I am being able to describe the point. Please elaborate if required or I can answer your queries.

Comment: @Marek: I am not very much interested in the 'upload'. This is because, I am creating the file on the server side. I jest need to add it to the doc library. The problem is that I am not creating the file from code or event in SharePoint, but from the Silverlight app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores the files **in a database**, not a folder.

[WebDAV access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx) may be what you're looking for - it's a backbone of the the *Explorer View* feature that allows a user to access a document library as if you were accessing a file system through a Windows Explorer window.

[image: Open with Explorer]

Comment: So, how is the file available in the explorer?

Comment: @Kangkan: Have you read the article I linked? The files can be accessed though Windows Explorer because the WebDAV protocol allows to directly manipulate file data stored in SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks. I have not read it yet. Thanks for the update again. So, to summarize, I cannot copy the file the way I was thinking. In the meantime, I have used the SP service to add the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure "incoming e-mail" properties for the document library, and assign an e-mail address.

After that, when you e-mail a document as attached to e-mail to this e-mail address, then attachment will be saved to that library by sharepoint automatically.

Comment: @Beyant: This is already implemented for something else. As the document is created on the server side, I am more interested in adding it to the doc library.

Comment: @Kangkan "I was thinking if like emailing to a list allows us to copy the file into the library" from this sentence, I thought you'd like to email a file and save to a library. There is no server side in silverlight btw that I know. I think you should check your needs and be sure about the terms you use. There are some conflicts in your words.

Comment: Can you please edit the post to remove the conflicting words? Or point them out, so that I can straighten them up?

Comment: @Kangkan sorry, but I couldn't understand your original aim. so that's not an option